# Cannot get class to be used

Tags: html, css, class

I have an H3 header with the class "calbri", using the following HTML:

```
<footer>
<div class='wrapper'>

<div class='col'>
<h3 class="calibri">Column Header</h3>
<p>Some text.</p>
</div>

</div>
</footer>
```

The styles are defined as follows:

```
footer .col h3  {font-size:20px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeueMediumCond';}
.calibri {font-family:Calibri,Verdana,Arial;}
```

The ".col h3" style is picked up just fine.
The added ".calibri" class however, is not.

Any help you could offer to explain why would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a point system in CSS. The selector with more points overrides the other selector. Let's compare 2 selectors

### The 1st selector:

```
footer .col h3{}
```

The above selector has 2 elements (footer and h3) and 1 class (.col); this results in **12 points**.

### The 2nd selector:

```
calibri{}
```

This has 1 class (.calibri); this results in **10 points**.

#### Conclusion:

Because 12>10 the 1st selector will override the 2nd selector.

If you want the 2nd selector to work, you need to give it more points. One way is to change the class to and id. So class="calibri" becomes id="calibri" which gives the calibri selector 100 points.

#### Further:

Here's an article for the point system: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity on CSS specificity.

You need to use `h3.calibri` instead.